# How to Upload Files in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have implemented in an form to upload a file in my project MVC asp net c#

Upload the file is not mandatory.

My problem:

1. when don't upload file I have confirmation that the values of form they where stored on database
2. If I upload file instead I don't have confirmation that the values of form they where stored on database, despite the fact that the values are registered in the database

e.g.

I open the view with the form

I fill the form data without attaching and uploading any file

The values are registered in the database

I have this return on alert popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var msg = '@ViewData["result"]';
        console.log(msg);
          if (msg > 0)
          {
              alert("Ok");
              var url = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
              window.location.href = url;
          }
});
</script>
```

I open the view with the form

I fill the form data attaching and uploading my file

The file is uploaded

The values are registered in the database

I don't have this return on alert popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var msg = '@ViewData["result"]';
        console.log(msg);
          if (msg > 0)
          {
              alert("Ok");
              var url = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
              window.location.href = url;
          }
});
</script>
```

How to do resolve this?

**view**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var msg = '@ViewData["result"]';
        console.log(msg);
          if (msg > 0)
          {
              alert("Ok");
              var url = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
              window.location.href = url;
          }
});
</script>
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PersonModel person, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
        var fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        if (fileExtension.ToString() == ".jpeg" ||
                    fileExtension.ToString() == ".jpg" ||
                    fileExtension.ToString() == ".gif" ||
                    fileExtension.ToString() == ".png")
        {
            fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_" + fileName.Trim() + fileExtension;
            var userfolderpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(userfolderpath);

            MTsqlinsert(person);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Please upload only image (jpg,gif,png)";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MTsqlinsert(person);
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(person);
    }

    return View(person);
}


   private void MTsqlinsert(PersonModel person)
    {
        try
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;

            using (MySqlConnection con =
                new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command =
                    new MySqlCommand("SP", con))
                {
                    command.Connection = con;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    ViewData["result"] = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = string.Format("<b>Message:</b> {0}<br /><br />", ex.Message);
            message += string.Format("<b>StackTrace:</b> {0}<br /><br />", ex.StackTrace.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty));
            message += string.Format("<b>Source:</b> {0}<br /><br />", ex.Source.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty));
            message += string.Format("<b>TargetSite:</b> {0}", ex.TargetSite.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty));
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you see in the console in both cases?

Comment: @DaveBarnett In both the cases. Always I need show popup if have upload file or not

Comment: Yes but your code has console.log(msg);  What is logged to the console in both cases?

Comment: @DaveBarnett if you are referring to vs2019 debugging the values are all correct

Comment: I'm referring to your JavaScript code. And what you see in the console when you bring up your browser's developer tools.